# Kubernetes secret types

Tags: kubernetes

Where are documented the "types" of secrets that you can create in kubernetes?

looking at different samples I have found "generic" and "docker-registry" but I have no been able to find a pointer to documentation where the different type of secrets are documented.

I always end in the k8s doc:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/

Thank you.

Comment: Openshift kubernetes implementation also have some useful information https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/secrets.html#types-of-secrets

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In [the kubectl docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#-em-secret-em-) you can see some of the available types. Also, in the command line

```
$ kubectl create secret --help
Create a secret using specified subcommand.

Available Commands:
  docker-registry Create a secret for use with a Docker registry
  generic         Create a secret from a local file, directory or literal value
  tls             Create a TLS secret

Usage:
  kubectl create secret [flags] [options]

Use "kubectl <command> --help" for more information about a given command.
Use "kubectl options" for a list of global command-line options (applies to all commands).
```

Comment: I didn't know the kubectl command line had help... Thank you!

Answer (score 42):

Here is a list of 'types' from the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/7693a1d5fe2a35b6e2e205f03ae9b3eddcdabc6b/pkg/apis/core/types.go#L4394-L4478):

```
SecretTypeOpaque SecretType = "Opaque"
[...]
SecretTypeServiceAccountToken SecretType = "kubernetes.io/service-account-token"
[...]
SecretTypeDockercfg SecretType = "kubernetes.io/dockercfg"
[...]
SecretTypeDockerConfigJson SecretType = "kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson"
[...]
SecretTypeBasicAuth SecretType = "kubernetes.io/basic-auth"
[...]
SecretTypeSSHAuth SecretType = "kubernetes.io/ssh-auth"
[...]
SecretTypeTLS SecretType = "kubernetes.io/tls"
[...]
SecretTypeBootstrapToken SecretType = "bootstrap.kubernetes.io/token"
```

Comment: For those like me who missed it initially--`generic` on the command line refers to the `Opaque` secret mentioned here